# Are any of the available flash 3d engines uses flash 10 "native 3d"

Tags: flash, papervision3d, away3d, sandy3d

As I understand flash 10 has some basic 3d features. My question is if any of the 3d engines available today (ppv3d, away, sandy, alternativa, am I missing one) uses these features and does this provide any performance and quality gains.

I'm working on some flash game that should contain 3d content. I'm using ppv3d and it just doesn't scale to what I need. Should I try anything else or does flash just not cut out for showing 100's of object all moving in real time?

thanks
Eli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think most of the flash 3D engine now uses the native 3D stuff, except maybe papervision 3D. You can probably easily verify this with Google.

It does provide a bit of a performance boost, but I think it's much more about the quality of the result. For example, if you create a textured cube and run it on an engine that use the "old projection trick", you will notice that the projection is deformed. The native projection in Flash 10 remove those artifacts.

For you're other question, well, it depends on the complexity of your objects; mainly the number of polygon, the size of your textures and the shader you use. You can probably put 100 cube with a simple color shader, but you might run into some problem if you're trying to create a AAA game.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Adobe announced yesterday (25/10/10) at MAX a new set of APIs for hardware-based 3D acceleration which could help with your performance issues... but you will obviously have to wait a while before you'll be able to incorporate them into your project.